# Magento Widgets - New Widget Instance Block Reference Bug

Tags: magento

If i target a block which is referenced in anything other than the `default` layout handle, the "Block Reference" select box in the new widget instance page (CMS > Widgets > Create New Widget Instance) can only pick up these blocks via the ajax controller that gets fired when the 'Page' select box changes.

Therefore, if I have a block referencing the cms_index_index layout handle, and i create a new widget instance which places a widget in this block, then every time i click into that widget instance in the admin are then the Block Reference dropdown looses its value.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: @benmarks - I have also noticed this in 1.6.x but never got round to looking at it further i.e. was it me or a bug.  Also, just checked in 1.7 and it behaves the same

Comment: Still getting this bug, very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug in the Varien JS library.

We got it fixed by extending `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Editor` and apply a fix (added a slash at the end of the line (`widget_target_id/`  in stead of `widget_target_id`) in method `_getPluginButtonsHtml()`. See below for the fixed line;

`'onclick'   => "widgetTools.openDialog('" . $this->getConfig('widget_window_url') . "widget_target_id/"`